# ApexCharts passing data

Tags: javascript, charts

Apex charts accepts data(series) in following format  series: `[{ name: 'Net Profit', data: [44, 55, 57, 56, 61, 58, 63, 60, 66] }]` . Where each item in data goes in different nests. What I need is pass data like `series: [{ name: 'Net profit', data: [23, 34, 45, 56]}] where data items will represent only one column.

Comment: Please share your code up until this point.

Answer (score 1):

```js
series: [{
    name: 'series-1',
    data: [{
      x: 'Team A',
      y: 13
    }, {
      x: 'Team B',
      y: 22
    }, {
      x: 'Team C',
      y: 43
    }, {
      x: 'Team D',
      y: 11
    }]
}]
```

In the above series, Team A is the 1st column and 13 is the value of that column.